# Determine whether this function finishes or runs forever

Tags: javascript

I am a little confused about this problem. Here is the code.

```
var finishes = function (f,x) {
//fill this in
}
```

Before attempting to implement this function, however, consider this:

```
var p = function (g) {
  if(finishes(g,g)){
    while (true) { }
  }
};
```

Basically, function p takes a function g and finishes whenever `g(g)` runs forever, and runs forever when `g(g)` finishes. What is the meaning, then, of the call `p(p)`? What does this suggest about the possibility of even writing the function "finishes"?

I am confused about the wording of this question. Could anyone explain?

Comment: please notice it will not run forever if finished return false

Comment: i did not expect that to be so fun

Answer (score 2):

what @aduch started to say, but didn't quite finish his question, is that the meaning of `P` function is not that it does something, but it's disprove something:

let's say that there is a function `finishes` that can tell you if another function ever stoping/halting. not what will happend if we'll run `p(p)`?

if `finishes` return true meaning `p` stops, then p will run forever.

if `finishes` return false meaning `p` never stops, then p will will stop!

thus there can be no function `finishes` that can tell you if a function halting

Answer (score 1):

This has been proven to be non deterministic so you can't really predict for any function as input whether it will end or not.

This is called the [halting problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Halting_problem).